# Incomplete types with Clang compiling c++11 code

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

[As this website shows](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#undep_incomplete), following code will not be supported in Clang using C++11:

```
class Node {
    vertex<Node> children;
};
```

An error will occur:

```
field has incomplete type 'Node'
```

But such code is supported in C++98 and other compilers such as gcc in C++11.

I know I can use

```
vertex<Node*>
```

instead, but at present I have some incompatibility issue with old code in C++98.

My question is, (1) can I compile such code using Clang in C++11? (2) I think a tree structure does inevitably need definition like above, without support of such feature, how can I realize such tree structure?

---

### update:

Sorry for forgetting to give definition of vertex, What about the following code:

```
class Node {
    vector<Node> children;
};
```

Just change vertex into a container vector. It is not valid in Clang with C++11, but ok with other compilers and with C++98.

---

### update again:

It seems vector works OK..but list fails

```
class Node {
    std::list<Node> children;
};
```

---

### update again:

Following is my code:

```
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Node {
    list<Node> nodes;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

or simpler:

```
#include <list>

class Node {
    std::list<Node> nodes;
};

int main() {}
```

I'm using Clang 4.0 and using the following command to compile:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp
```

The error is

```
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/list:212:9: error: field has incomplete type 'Node'
```

Comment: It depends on the definition of `vertex`.

Comment: You're misquoting the site, as inside `vertex`, the `Node` you pass in indeed **does** depend on a template parameter (it **is** a template parameter). This really depends on what `vertex` does with its template parameter, as Alex says.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain, what about change vertex to vector? In my definition of vertex, it essentially involves a vector.

Comment: If you change it to `std::vector`, it should work.

Comment: @Angew, I'm quite sorry...please check my update.

Comment: @HanXu There must be something else wrong, which you aren't showing. It [compiles just fine](http://liveworkspace.org/code/mRwlM$1) with `vector`.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain, oh it is...but if changed into std::list, it fails..

Comment: @Angew, I'm in such a hurry and mess..sorry..It should be std::list, which is ok in C++98 but failed in C++11

Comment: @HanXu [Still works fine](http://liveworkspace.org/code/mRwlM$2). If you want us to spend time to help you, invest some effort and prepare a minimal example which demonstrates the error, something we could paste to ideone or liveworkspace and see for ourselves.

Comment: @Angew, I'm using Clang++4.0, which liveworkspace seems doesn't support.

Comment: @Angew, please check my latest update...REALLY sorry for such a mess.

Comment: @HanXu Still, this simply *should* work. Do you also get the error if you simply slap `#include <list>` and `int main() {}` before the code of your "update again" and compile it as a separate file?

Comment: @Angew, if I change list to vector, there is no error.

Comment: @Angew, if I just slap #include <list> and int main() {} to my initial code, there is still the same error.

Comment: @Angew, I have edited my latest update. BTW, those codes are compiled in separate files.

Comment: @Angew, OK, I will check that. THANK YOU VERY MUCH, especially for you patience. You know, I'm driven mad by this problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it does not compile, it means that `vertex` attempts to use `Node` in a way that requires it to be completely defined. Most of the time, this implies (for generic code) using the size of the `T` parameter:

- either explicitly (`sizeof(T)`)
- or implicitly `template <typename T> struct vertex { T data[3]; };` is using the size of `T` to compute the layout of the type

Another (possible) issue, is relying on methods of `T` for some template instantiation; however this is much rarer.

You can avoid this requirement by changing the definition of `vertex`. Not knowing what it is though, we won't be able to get much more specific...

Comment: @HanXu: `std::vector` may be used with incomplete types *if* the Standard Library implementation you are using makes the additional guarantee that it's okay; `libc++` does not allow it. Otherwise the C++ Standard says in §17.6.4.8 [res.on.functions]: [...] In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases: [...] if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component.

Comment: Thanks, in fact I mistook vector for list. std::vector works fine, but std::list fails.Anyway, your explanation is clear, thank you very much.