# graph/tree implementation with incomplete types

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

The problem has been discussed many times before. What to do if one needs:

```
struct Node
{
  ::std::vector<Node> nodes_;
};
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590580/how-do-i-fix-my-stl-style-container-to-hold-incomplete-or-abstract-types) one gets the impression that (smart) pointers to `Node*` might be the canonical solution. This implies some additional indirection and a corresponding performance hit. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758690/incomplete-types-with-clang-compiling-c11-code), we see, that `libstdc++` supports `::std::vector<T>` instantiations, where `T` is an incomplete type, but not `libc++`. This is hardly portable. But one solution might be a portable `::std::vector` lookalike container that supports incomplete types. Finally, we can do:

```
template <::std::size_t I = 0>
struct Node
{
  ::std::vector<Node<I + 1> > nodes_;
};

template <>
struct Node<20>
{
};
```

Which imposes limitations on our graph/tree. Do there exist additional workarounds, due to the fact that a `Node` contains `Node`s, but is an incomplete type at the point of declaration of  `::std::vector<Node> nodes_;`?

Comment: There is a boost library for this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/container/containers_of_incomplete_types.html .

Comment: @zch Will you make your comment an answer? I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Boost containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/container.html) handle incomplete types and are portable.

So your Node can become :

```
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>

struct Node
{
  boost::container::vector<Node> nodes_;
};
```